# jQuery serialize. Decode string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма с входными данными

```
<form>
 <input type="text" name="name" value="Имя публикации" />
</form>
```

С помощью jQuery достаю данные

```
inputs = $("form").serialize().split('&');
```

На выходе получаю

```
["name=%D0%98%D0%BC%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8"]
```

Как привести строку к нормальному виду? Если использовать decodeURI, то пробелы заменяются плюсами.

Мне нужно отправить форму аяксом с данными и файлами

```
function getData(form) {
        /* get data from form */
        var data = new FormData()
        inputs = form.serialize().split('&');
        inputs.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
            var tmp = item.split('=');
            data.append(tmp[0],decodeURIComponent(tmp[1].replace(/\+/g, ' ')));
        });
        /* get files */
        form.find("input[type='file']").each(function(){
            var key = $(this).attr('name');
            var file = $(this).prop('files')[0];
            if (file !== 'undefined') {
                data.append(key, file);
            }
        });
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: `decodeURIComponent(t).replace(/\+/g, ' ')`?

Comment: @Other Спасибо. Работает )

Comment: А зачем вы их так достаёте?

Comment: @Other Мне нужно аяксом отправить форму с данными. Ну вот я и собираю данные.

Comment: Тогда зачем эти дополнительные действия с разбиванием по амперсанду и декодированию? Просто сделайте `$.post($(form).attr('action'), $(form).serialize(), successCallback)`.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev тогда не отправляет вложенные файлы ((

Answer (score 1):

Недавно тоже столкнулся с проблемой отправки AJAX'ом формы с файлами. Честно говоря, так и не смог заставить jQuery это сделать. А вот с ваниальным вариантом проблем не возникло:

```
$('#job-form').submit(function(event) {
    if(window.FormData !== undefined) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var form = this;
        $(form).find('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

        var formData = new FormData(form);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', $(form).attr('action'), true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-REQUESTED-WITH', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if(xhr.status == 200) {
                    result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    if(result.status == 'ok') {
                        form.reset();
                        showModal(result.info);
                    }
                    else if(result.status == 'error') {
                        for(var ndx in result.info) {
                            var holder = $(form).find('[name=' + result.info[ndx].key + ']').closest('.form-group');
                            holder.addClass('has-error');
                            if(result.info[ndx].key == '__all__') {
                                showModal(result.info[ndx].desc, 'Ошибка');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    showModal('Ошибка отправки формы. Попробуйте повторить попытку позже.', 'Ошибка');
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send(formData);
    }
});
```